# Regular Expression for custom query language's date format Java

Tags: java, regex

I have date format in below pattern.

- dates [2014_09_01,2014_09_01]
- dates 2014_04_01
- last_nn_days nn = days in number

Example:

- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates[2014_09_01,2014_09_15]
- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates 2014_09_01
- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates last_30_days

From this: I want to generate a new query with

- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates [%s,%s]
- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates [%s,%s]
- select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and
  dates [%s,%s]

I want to search these Strings and want to replace this part with dates [%s,%s].
Could it be possible with Regex in Java?

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj : I have added example

Comment: PreparedStatement ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex to replace all the strings mentioned with `[%s,%s]`

```
(dates)\\s*(?:\\[\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2},\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}\\]|\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}|last_\\d{2}_days)
```

Replacement string:

```
$1 [%s,%s]
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/hA9vA7/4)

```
String s = "select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates[2014_09_01,2014_09_15]\n" + 
            "select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates 2014_09_01\n" + 
            "select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates last_30_days\n";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("(dates)\\s*(?:(?:\\[\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2},)?\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}\\]?|last_\\d{2}_days)", "$1 [%s,%s]"));
```

**Output:**

```
select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates [%s,%s]
select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates [%s,%s]
select * from someTable t where t.name is not null and dates [%s,%s]
```

Comment: Have you heard about PreparedStatement? :)

Comment: no, sorry i'm not familiar in java.

Comment: I know it. This requirement is for creation of template from query.  and then use it in a generic way where user can use this query  replace %s with proper dates and get the response.

Comment: Hi @AvinashRaj: I have modified expression so that it can accept spaces also
(dates)\\s*(?:\\[\\s*\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}\\s*,\\s*\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}\\s*]|\\d{4}_\\d{2}_\\d{2}|last_\\d{2}_days)